# binding jquery function with form loaded after page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a jquery form that is submitted with FormData (and using iframe if formdata isn't available) however when the form is submitted another form is generated. as this form is going to use a jquery function to submit, the jquery function doesn't seem to be binded with the form so instead of using event.stopDefault(); it submits to its default i.e. test.php

Another words my question is: when a form is loaded by ajax is there a method/way to reload/bind the jquery function to the new form?

Example Code:

js code that i have tried:

```
$(document).on('#resize', submit, function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if(window.FormData === undefined){
                alert("Form Data not supported");
            }
            else{
                var iframe = $('<iframe name="resizeiframe" id="resizeiframe" style="display: none" />');

                $("body").append(iframe);

                var form = $('#resize');
                form.attr("action", "resizer.php");
                form.attr("method", "post");
                form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
                form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
                form.attr("target", "postiframe");
                form.attr("file", $('#resizeimage').val());
                form.submit();

                $("#resizeiframe").load(function () {
                    iframeContents = $("#resizeiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                    $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
                    $("#resizeiframe").remove();
                    $(document).find('#resizeiframe').remove();
                });
            }


});
```

form that is been submited after been generated by ajax but submitting regardless:

```
<form id="resize" action="resizer.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                <input type="hidden" id="resizeimage" name="image" value="'.$new_name.'"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Crop Image" class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" />
            </form>
```

p.s i have tried removing the onsubmit but this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Search for delegation using .on() {prefered on jq 1.7+} or .delegate() just like @RPM's answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff i have tried both delegate and on but neither seem to work for me. i have updated with the code

Comment: Firstly, should be: `$(document).on('submit','#resize',handler)`

Comment: sorry just changed RPM answer from delegate to on and forgot to change these over! However the script still runs fine but submits as default

Comment: sorted it your correction was correct however in the process of testing it i had changed document to "body" and not changed it back. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is loaded dynamically then jQuery isn't able to be binded to it by using the default `x.submit()` functions.

Use something like this:

```
 $(document).delegate('#id_of_my_dynamic_form', 'submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // now you have the form
     // maybe serialize the form

     // var s = $(this).serialize();
 });
```

Comment: i have tried  $(document).on('#resize', submit, function(e) { after the $(document).ready(function() has been closed and it still seems to submit. I will update my code

Comment: @LiamSorsby change `submit` to `'submit'`

Comment: can't possibly thank you enough. Spent 2 hours figuring this out

Comment: AbhyudayaSrinet I'm glad it was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your first line to this:

```
$(body).on('submit', '#resize', function(e) {
```

You need to bind to an element that IS present on `pageLoad`